# Behaviour for 'rel' attribute: prop() vs attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could someone explain me this (odd) behaviour in jQuery? Here's fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hdLMu/1/

The question is, why jQuery won't set `rel` to `tooltip` when calling `.prop()` method, while `.attr()` works just fine?

Moreover, both method works when setting up `type`.
My only guess is that `.prop()` performs some validation? As `rel` is not allowed to use with `button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before **jQuery 1.6** `attr()`was used for both HTML attributes and Object properties.

After **jQuery 1.6** `attr()` is used for HTML attributes *only*, like `href`or `rel`, `class` or any other.

`prop()` is now used for Object properties like

```
var Obj = {
    propOne: 'somevalue'
}
```

or

```
selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ...
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> ... the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.

The key phrase for using `prop()` is:

***Properties do not have corresponding (HTML) attributes and are only properties.***

---

**Examples from the docs:**

```
elem.checked 
// true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state

$(elem).prop( 'checked')    
// true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state

elem.getAttribute('checked') 
// "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; 
// does not change

$(elem).attr('checked') (1.6) 
// "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; 
// does not change

$(elem).attr('checked') (1.6.1+) 
// "checked" (String) Will change with checkbox state

$(elem).attr('checked') (pre-1.6) 
// true (Boolean) Changed with checkbox state
```